# Nef-ness of restriction of tangent bundle on Fano

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Fano manifold of Picard number one. Let $X^{\text{free}} \subset X$ be the subset of $X$ such that any rational curve in $X$, which intersects $X^{\text{free}}$ is free.
We say, divior $D$ on $X^{\text{free}}$ is nef if for every curve $C \subset X^{\text{free}}, \overline{D}. \overline{C} \ge 0$, where $\overline{D}$ denotes its closure in $X$. Similarly we define the nef-ness of a vector bundle on $X^{\text{free}}$.

Question (1): Is $TX\vert_{X^{\text{free}}}$  nef ?

Question(2): Is $TX\vert_{X^{\text{free}}}$ globally generated ?

Question (3): If $TX$ is not nef, can $X \setminus X^{\text{free}}$ be of co-dimension at least 2 ?

Comment: I recommend that you test this against the parahoric specialization of the orthogonal Grassmannian as in Pasquier—Perrin.